# Lua Functions .. Optional Table

Tags: function, lua

How to pass table in lua function which is optional.

For example

```lua
function test(options)
   local a = options.a
end
```

---

this function should work as both

```lua
test(options)
```

and

```lua
test()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function test(options)

  options = options or {}
  local a = options.a or 0 -- or whatever it defaults to

end
```

You simply `or` the optional values with their default value.
If the value has not been provided and hence is `nil` it will resolve to `or`ed value.

This is a shorter version of

```
function test(options)
  if not options then
    options = {}
  end
  local a = 0
  if options.a then
    a = options.a    
  end
end
```

Comment: With the only exception of `options.a` being the actual `false` value in which case the `or` trick won't produce the correct result.  Better check explicitly for `nil`.

Comment: @tonypdmtr yeah you're right but if you expect something like false you wouldn't usually have 0 as a default value. providing any true value but a table for options would cause an error anyway. simple code examples usually don't come with extensive validation and error handling. you cannot `or` false as a default value either